# JUnit assertEquals( ) fails for two objects

Tags: junit, equals

I created a class and overridden the equals() method. When I use `assertTrue(obj1.equals(obj2))`, it will pass the test; however, `assertEquals(obj1, obj2)` will fail the test. Could someone please tell the reason why?

Comment: we need to see the code for the equals method

Comment: Are `obj1` and `obj2` of the same type?

Comment: Did you try in debugging mode that the overridden equal is used by assertEquals ?

Comment: can you check/post your equals method syntax, most likely you are not overriding the `equals` in the Object class, instead you must be writing your own version of it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't *actually* overridden `equals` - that you've overloaded it instead. Use the `@Override` annotation to find this sort of thing out at compile time.

In other words, I suspect you've got:

```java
public boolean equals(MyClass other)
```

where you should have:

```java
@Override // Force the compiler to check I'm really overriding something
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

In your working assertion, you were no doubt calling the overloaded method as the compile-time type of `obj1` and `obj2` were both `MyClass` (or whatever your class is called). JUnit's `assertEquals` will only call `equals(Object)` as it doesn't know any better.

Comment: It works when I changed public boolean equals(MyClass other) to public boolean equals(Object other). Thanks Jon.

Comment: @nikel: The fact that `Date` is mutable makes it hard to implement equality nicely - you could have a `HashSet<Date>`, and once you'd mutated an entry you wouldn't be able to find it again...

Comment: Re-adding the comment - I wonder why Date does not override its equals implementation...

Comment: A follow up  - I created two Date objects with equal value(hours, minutes, seconds, etc...). 
Calling Junit's assertEquals on them gives true, but since Date does not say Override in its definition, should not the Junit assertEquals call the Object equals? and hence return false?

Comment: @nikel: Looking at the docs, it *does* override equals... not sure what you mean by "does not say Override in its definition"

Comment: Yes, the docs does say it. However, i was looking at the source from - http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Date.java.html which does not have an override annotation above the equals method...so i thought it does not override

Comment: @nikel: The override annotation is just a way of getting the compiler to check that it really *is* overriding. It isn't *required*.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for `assertEquals` (from [Github](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L117)):

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
        Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null)
        return;
    if (expected != null && isEquals(expected, actual))
        return;
    else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage= message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
}

private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    return expected.equals(actual);
}
```

I can think of only one case where this behaves the way you described - if your `equals` method is not handling comparisons to `null` values correctly.

Comment: You're assuming that the `equals` called by JUnit is the same `equals` called in the passing version...

Comment: @Jon Yes, just noticed that you had correctly guessed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to override the equals() function. It's a lot easier to do if you're using some IDE. For instance, in eclipse, in your java file, right click -> source -> Generate hashCode() and equals(), will do it. Run the tests again and it should pass now.

It is also a good practice to generate these methods as they have their own advantages which will make your code stronger and make it comply to the OOAD principals more.