# Is adding code just for unit testing sake accepted practice

Tags: java, junit

I am testing two objects using junits, and it appears that I need to override `equals` in the object so that junit can do a valid assertEquals.

But other than junits, there no place in code I need to ever compare two objects. Thus, keeping unit testing aside, I never really need to use the overriden `equals`.

This means I am adding code only for unit testing.

Is this a necessary evil ? Is there any work around ?

Comment: I am not aware about Junit requiring you to override equals. Can you post more context please ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060848/junit-assertequals-fails-for-two-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should one override equals method for asserting the object equality in a unit test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180044/should-one-override-equals-method-for-asserting-the-object-equality-in-a-unit-te)

Answer (score 0):

Provided the state of the object you want to test is available (say, you want to test the name of a person and your `Person` object has `.getName()`), then you can write a custom matcher.

How you write such a matcher is *very* dependent on what testing libraries you use, but here is a very small example when using TestNG and fest-assert:

```
import org.fest.assertions.GenericAssert;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

public final class PersonAssert
    extends GenericAssert<PersonAssert, Person>
{
    private final Person person;

    public static PersonAssert assertPerson(final Person person)
    {
        return new PersonAssert(message);
    }

    private PersonAssert(final Person person)
    {
        super(Person.class, person);
        this.person = person;
    }

    public PersonAssert hasName(final String expected)
    {
        assertEquals(person.getName(), expected,
            "Who is this guy? I expected " + expected + " but got " + person.getName());
        return this;
    }

    public PersonAssert isOfAge(final int age) { /* etc */ }


    // etc
}
```

In your code you can then use:

```
import static my.package.PersonAssert.assertPerson;

// ...

assertPerson(person).hasName("Jimmy the hands");
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is of course possible to implement a custom matcher, like fge suggests, I personally also often choose to just override equals in a tested code, because it's usually just much simpler (e.g. using IDEs code generator). Basically - in some cases - one should consider if blindly sticking to *practices* isn't just making your life harder....